# DIL Chip information required

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, chip-design

I have a "Delay Timer Switch, with delay adjustable from 0 to 10 seconds". It operates from 12V.

Can anybody tell me that what is this part in this PCB?
I guess it is DIL chip (I am a beginner and don't know for what we use these chips) so can anybody explain that what this does?
why we use it in circuits?

what is the function and circuit of the chip shown here?
please explain.

[image]

Comment: Actually it is a SOIC chip. But DIL/SOIC is not what it does, merely what its form factor is. From the part number writen on it, it is an NE555 (A classic 555 Timer). There is a datasheet for it here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf . Generally these are used for generating clock pulses at different frequencies depending on how they are wired up. Without more information about what that thing is, it is hard to say what they are using the 555 for.

Comment: As you knew it was a delay timing relay you should have said so in your question - and should have updated your question to show this once you had provided the information in a comment. | You can buy si,ilar on ebay eg [**this one](http://www.amazon.com/PowerArt-Switch-Adjustable-Module-Electrical/dp/B00CRYUSR2) for $US 3.429 with free shipping.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I am not an expert, I am still learning basics of electronics. I don't wana buy these stuff, I wana do it my self or maybe joining the parts

Comment: @Andriopak - Wanting to do it yourself is excellent. **BUT** describing what you are wanting to do is essential if you want maximum & prompt help. Asking what a component is is not the ideal way to get there. By all means mention it BUT if you want a delayed action relay SAY SO. If just a relay SAY so. If something else SAY SO. Also, very important, if you are wanting to do it yourself, saying so "up front" will help greatly, as that is what questions here are ideally about.

Comment: @Andriopak - Wanting to do it yourself is excellent. **BUT** describing what you are wanting to do is essential if you want maximum & prompt help. Asking what a component is is not the ideal way to get there. By all means mention it BUT if you want a delayed action relay SAY SO. If just a relay SAY so. If something else SAY SO. Also, very important, if you are wanting to do it yourself, saying so "up front" will help greatly, as that is what questions here are ideally about....

Comment: [**This circuit from Spehro's answer**](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/244755/YL-21.png) will allow you to see what parts to get. **BUT** if you tell us what you want to achieve, rather than asking what an IC does, you may get a much more useful answer. | We'd actually like to help. Helping us do so is helpful :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I got the schematic from Spehro and I think no difficulties left to understand but to do it.

Comment: And we STILL do not know what "IT" is :-(. You are now replicating the functionality and exact circuitry of an Asian relay-timer module. Does this do what you want? - we cannot tell. Is there a better solution that we could have advised on? - we cannot tell. Is there much that Spehro on related issues if asked? Oh yes. | What is the output voltage and current and load? Is the load reactive? Do 'creepage' clearances apply or matter? What sort of relay suits and why? We can't be sure as we don't know any relevant destails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an [555 Timer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/555_timer_IC) based on the IC's label, [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm555.pdf):
[image]

To tell you what is the exact role of this IC in this circuit you should provide more information about this PCB.

Comment: This is a timing relay, I think i don't need to explain it more

Comment: Then in this case, this IC provides the clock signal / control signal for the relay.

Comment: If i don't use this IC and create the circuit using normal resistances,relays and other parts which are inside it, (I know its costly) will it work or I must use this one?

Comment: Theoretically, if you want to make this timer on your own based on its schematic, it could work. But it is not guaranteed and your circuit will be a lot bigger and as you said more expensive. So I recommend you to use the timer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is a SOIC chip. But DIL/SOIC is not what it does, merely what its form factor is.

From the part number written on it, it is an NE555 (A classic 555 Timer). There is a datasheet for it here: ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf .

Generally these are used for generating clock pulses at different frequencies, periods, etc. depending on how they are wired up. Without more information about what that thing is, it is hard to say what they are using the 555 for.

*But*, having done a quick google search for the label on the PCB (YL-21), it turns out this is a device which turns on a relay after a variable interval (between 1-10 seconds), so in this case the 555 is being used as a mono-stable multivibrator.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://www.mikrocontroller.net/topic/355860) is the schematic:

[image: http://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/244755/YL-21.png]

When power is applied, assuming C1 (the 100uF electrolytic) is starting from 0V, it charges through R1 (the blue multiturn variable resistor). The output is driven high immediately, driving the relay through the bipolar transistor. After the voltage at pins 6 and 2 drops to 33% of Vcc, the output goes low and the relay drops out.

Time should be around 11 seconds maximum (\$100\mu F * 100K\Omega * ln(3)\$).

The chip is an old-fashioned bipolar [NE555](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ne555.pdf), which costs pennies in volume.